# Google maps - markerClusterer zoomOnclick factor?

Tags: google-maps

I'm using markerClusterer w/ googlemaps. Suppose I have one cluster with 10 markers -- if I *single* click, it zooms in so far that only one marker is visible and I have to zoom out and / or drag the map around to find the other nearby markers.

Double clicking zooms in smaller increments (which is what I want for single click).

Is there an option to set the zoom factor for *single* click zooming? gridSize and maxZoom don't seem to affect this, though I may be approaching this wrong?

```
// clusterer options
let mcOptions = {
  gridSize: 10,
  maxZoom: 10,
  zoomOnClick: true,
  minimumClusterSize: 2,
};

// map
let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapContainer'), {
  zoom: 4,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0, -102.0),
  styles: mapStyles,
  zoomControl: true,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  scaleControl: false,
  streetViewControl: false,
  rotateControl: false,
  fullscreenControl: false,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
});
```

Comment: What MarkerClusterer are you using?  In my maps a single click on a cluster unclusters that cluster and zooms to its bounds.  ([example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_clustered.html)).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. First make sure you have the very latest markerClusterer code. (I switched from a script call in the head to adding the package to my project and importing it into my map component.)

```
  // import MarkerClusterer (or call it in a script tag)
  import MarkerClusterer from '@google/markerclusterer';

  // create new cluster   
  markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);

  // add a listener to the cluster click and do what you want inside
  markerCluster.addListener('clusterclick', (cluster) => {
    let currentZoom = map.getZoom();
    map.setCenter(cluster.getCenter());
    map.setZoom(currentZoom + 4);
  });

  // add zoom listener to map and do what you want inside
  map.addListener('zoom_changed', () => {
    let currentZoom = map.getZoom();
    if (currentZoom > 7) {
      map.setMapTypeId('hybrid');
    } else {
      map.setMapTypeId('roadmap');
    }
  });
```